# How to create a Leaflet map layer from 30,000+ points?

Tags: leaflet, layer, mapbox, geojson, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm building a map app for which I have to show the volume of our user base. 
I have 30,000+ coordinates and I am wondering what is the best way to display them without impinging too much on performance.

I figured creating a custom tile/layer would be the best way to do so but haven't found how to do it. I have looked at Mapbox but haven't found what I'm looking for.

The app is currently using Leaflet and the Angular-leaflet-directive.

I'm looking forward to hearing your suggestions.

Edit: I'm trying to do something similar to this visually http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/paths/3000-items-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about "density", you could be interested in showing a Heat map (see available [heat maps plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#heatmaps)). [Heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) may fit your need, as it advertises being able to manage 40k+ data points.

If you still need to access each individual point, you would be more interested in [clustering plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#clusteringdecluttering). The most popular one being [MarkerCluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster), but the current release version is a little slow at initialization (a few seconds) for that amount of points. A next release should be published soon that corrects for this performance issue. If you cannot wait, try [PruneCluster](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/PruneCluster), it is much faster but it does not animate.

That being said, you will still need to download those 30k+ points before being able to display them (either through clustering or as a heat map), so make sure your data is lean! Another solution would be to generate your heat map tiles on server side.

Comment: I have played with heatmaps but this is not the result I'm looking for.
I do intend to generate the tiles on the server side but I'm just not sure how to do so. I have edited my question with an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the links ! I have found [MaskCanvas](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-maskcanvas) that I believe will fit my needs. Therefore I accepted your answer